# Table.Sort creating null fields in PowerQuery that once had data

Tags: powerquery, missing-data

I have the following code in PowerQuery

```
let
    Source = #"MyDB",
    _SomeTable = Source{[Schema="",Item="SomeTable"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(_SomeTable, each ([DateField3] = null)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Summary"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns", {"RelatedData"}, RelatedData, {"ID"}, "RelatedData.1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"RelatedData"}),
    #"Expanded QueryFrom.1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "RelatedData.1", {"RelatedData"}, {"RelatedData"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded RelatedData.1",{"ID", "FK1", "FK2", "RelatedData", "DateField1", "DateField2", "DateField3"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Reordered Columns",{{"DateField2", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Everything works fine until it gets to #"Sorted Rows", and then for some reason at this step some of my fields in the result set become null (though they weren't null prior to the sort).  I can't pinpoint exactly what the error is, but I know that if I remove the Table.Sort, I get all the data (however, my data needs to be sorted).

Has anyone else run into issues like this caused by Table.Sort, and are there any specific work-arounds?  To me this seems like a bug, as sorting data should not change the data, just the way it is indexed in an array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bad table reference in the `#"Reordered Columns"` step. Could this work?

```
let
    Source = #"MyDB",
    _SomeTable = Source{[Schema="",Item="SomeTable"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(_SomeTable, each ([DateField3] = null)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Summary"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns", {"RelatedData"}, RelatedData, {"ID"}, "RelatedData.1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"RelatedData"}),
    #"Expanded QueryFrom.1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "RelatedData.1", {"RelatedData"}, {"RelatedData"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded QueryFrom.1",{"ID", "FK1", "FK2", "RelatedData", "DateField1", "DateField2", "DateField3"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Reordered Columns",{{"DateField2", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Answer (score 0):

If Marcus' answer doesn't work (to solve the odd reference) I would hazard a guess that the columns always had null, and you didn't notice until the sort took place.   If you filter for [x]null in those columns before even doing the sort do you see them show up?